# Automatically lock resources based on the tags - Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-resource-lock

I would like to find a way to automatically lock resources when they have a specific tag and value in Microsoft Azure.

For example, if the resource has a tag "Important resource" set to "yes", a "CanNotDelete" lock should be created on this resource.
I have tried some things with the policies and the "DeployIfNotExists" effect but I don't find what I'm looking for (not even sure if that effect could possibly do what I want). I don't really know where to look to solve my problem.

I guess I could do this with Powershell but I would like it to be automatic when new resources are created without having to launch the Powershell script to lock the resources.

I hope everything is clear, thank you.

Comment: This might help you a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602082/azure-policy-delete-lock-on-resource-group

Comment: I can detect the resources with the tags but I don't know how to deploy a lock on them. To deploy a lock on a resource with the ARM templates, I have to use `"type": "{resourceProviderNamespace}/{resourceType}/providers/locks"` but I don't know how to get the resourceProviderNamespace and the resourceType of that specific resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how frequently you're deploying or how time sensitive your requirements are, but if you can write a solution in Powershell (it looks like [Get-AzResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-3.7.0) with the -Tag param would work) you could run it in [a timer-triggered Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell) at basically no cost.